# Import PayPal Transactions to Dynamics NAV

Tags: paypal, dynamics-nav

We have created a import for PayPal transactions to our Dynamics NAV ERP System based on th CSV file which can be downloaded from paypal. Within this CSV file we have troubles with the fact that there is no Carriege Return at the end of a line.

I'm trying to find out id there are other ways to export transactions from PayPal other that comma or tab delimited textfiles? We would prefer something like xml or json id this is possible..

Comment: Then what is there at the end of the line? Could you post a screenshot or the file?

Comment: sound's crazy, but you can always write your own code to process a CSV file. It's very easy. You can handle any line endings then.

Comment: In Dynamics Nav 2009 or higher you can use Xmlports to export to / import from XML files. These work well with relatively flat XML structures. In earlier versions the only way is DIY as azatoth suggested.